# Insert text in ToC but not in Shorttoc

Tags: table-of-contents, shorttoc

I'm trying to find a way to insert some text at the end of the table of contents, without it being written in the shorttoc.

To be precise, my advisor does not want me to write "Written with \LaTeX" on the first page, so I decided to put it at the very end. But now it appears two times : in the shorttoc and in the table of content.

I suppose there's a way to use "addtocontent" to do this, but I don't see how ...

Here's a MWE, and i'm trying to get rid of the first occurence of "Écrit avec Latex" :

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt,oneside]{book} 
\usepackage{shorttoc}
\begin{document}

\shorttableofcontents{LA}{0}


 \chapter{Solala}

 \addtocontents{toc}{ \vfill \protect\begin{flushright}  Document écrit avec \LaTeX.\par \protect\end{flushright}}


\tableofcontents

\end{document}
```

Comment: Why don't you simply say `\tableofcontents\vfill\begin{flushright}...\end{flushright}`?

Comment: `\shorttableofcontents` just reads `\jobname.toc`, so you could use a condition that is switched on/off based on the contents you're using. However, @egreg's proposal seems more fitting (and cleaner).

Comment: @Werner That was also my first idea, but then the simpler way presented itself.

Comment: This works, but the text is either displayed on another page (if the expression is after \tableofcontent), or displayed on the right page, but still opens a new, empty page ... any idea how to avoid this new page ?

Answer (score 1):

I would definitely go with the proposal made by `egreg` in comments, but if you absolutely want to play with `\addtocontents`, here is a way:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt,oneside]{book} 
\usepackage{shorttoc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\def\LaTeXstamp{\gdef\LaTeXstamp{\vfill \begin{flushright}  
Document écrit avec \LaTeX.\par \end{flushright}}}

\AtEndDocument{\addtocontents{toc}{\protect\LaTeXstamp}}

\begin{document}

\shorttableofcontents{LA}{0}

\chapter{Solala}

\tableofcontents

\end{document}
```

Comment: Works great in the MWE. But once I put it in the bigger file, it just does not display anything ... I'll try to find where this fail ... maybe some wrong packages !

Comment: @ThomsMorel does the `.toc` file end with a line `\LaTeXstamp`? (anyway, please consider using `egreg`'s proposal, it is a better way).

Comment: Yes you're right, in my bigger project, the .toc ends with \LaTeXstamp ! So does the mwe.toc. But in the first case, nothing appears on the page ...

I'd like to use egreg's proposal, which is simpler, but the new page bothers me, and I dont know how to get rid of it ;-)

Comment: @ThomsMorel `.toc` ending with `\LaTeXstamp` is what my proposal does. So, if it does not work, it could be that `\shorttableofcontents` uses something else than the `.toc` file, due to some added package. You should check which files are created in the repertory where your `.tex` file resides.

Comment: I don't really understand ... I'm using the "bredele" class, something made by a french guy for french thesis criting. Works normally well.

What I don't get is why, while in both case the .toc file ends with \LaTeXstamp, in the big tex file this does not display the line ...

Comment: @ThomsMorel I have downloaded `bredele.cls` which loads dozens of packages and as you said the `MWE` works fine. Could you try to produce a minimal non-working example... else it's very hard to say why it goes wrong.